# Using NSCondition properly

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, synchronization

I was looking at the [NSCondition documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html) examples and got a little confused:

---

> Whenever you use a condition object, the first step is to lock the
>   condition. Locking the condition ensures that your predicate and task
>   code are protected from interference by other threads using the same
>   condition. Once you have completed your task, you can set other
>   predicates or signal other conditions based on the needs of your code.
>   You should always set predicates and signal conditions while holding
>   the condition object’s lock.

Listing 4-3  Using a Cocoa condition

```
[cocoaCondition lock];
while (timeToDoWork <= 0)
    [cocoaCondition wait];

timeToDoWork--;

// Do real work here.

[cocoaCondition unlock];
```

Listing 4-4  Signaling a Cocoa condition

```
[cocoaCondition lock];
timeToDoWork++;
[cocoaCondition signal];
[cocoaCondition unlock];
```

---

Let's say the thread using the Cocoa condition is blocking at `[cocoaCondition wait]`. Since `[cocoaCondition unlock]` has not been called yet, it also has ownership of the `cocoaCondition` lock.

My question is--how does the condition ever get signaled? Once another thread tries to acquire the `cocoaCondition` lock, won't it block?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is part of how the condition works: `wait`ing on a condition variable atomically releases the underlying lock for the duration of the wait operation and re-aquires it, once the condition variable is signalled. Likewise, the `signal` delivery won't happen until the thread signalling the variable releases the variable's underlying lock.